# remove main report tab in crystal reports viewer on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

Although I have found some solutions to this problem, none of them refer to ASP.NET application and the Viewer used there.
Does anyone know how to remove the "Main Report" tab from  the Crystal reports viewer on an ASP.NET page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.
It is the property of the CrystalReportViewer control called HasDrilldownTabs. Set it to false.

That's it.